# How to store a list of GameObjects with all components (scripts, colliders etc)

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, save, gameobject

I'm storing information of all my buildings in my game in a List. Every building has a script attached with its info. 
I'm using a Save Tool, which loads the list again, if I start my game, the GameObjects appear, but without the necessary informations. Is there an easy way to fix this? Can I make a second List with all Scripts for examples and reattach them after restarting?

This is my List:

```
    public static List<GameObject> buildingsList = new List<GameObject>();
```

And everything I'm doing at the moment is reloading this List in the Awake Method, and the buildins Appear, but without any informations.

```
    private void Awake()
    {
        if (ES3.KeyExists("buildingsList"))
            buildingsList = ES3.Load<List<GameObject>>("buildingsList");
        else
            Debug.Log("There aren't any buildings yet!");
    }
```

If I build a new house in Game, following code gets called:

```
      buildingsList.Add(clone);
      ES3.Save<List<GameObject>>("buildingsList", buildingsList);
```

The ES3 Loads exactly this List when restarting. The problem is, that the list is only containing the GameObjects, without any information about attached stuff to it.

Comment: I fear this question is to broad. It seems that this ES3 uses some kind of a dictionary to store information. Converting it to "deep copy" all properties of a GameObject would require some major modifications and reflection. Also not all types and components are supported see [Supported types](https://docs.moodkie.com/easy-save-3/es3-supported-types/)

Comment: @derHugo Does that mean that the List with the GameObjects contains all information about attached scirpts and their saved values initialy, and I loose this informations with the ES3 Method? - Because in the Supported Types Documentations is written that it supports all components of a GameObject.

Comment: A `List<GameObject>` stores references to `GameObject`s. It doesn't store any further information. In Unity you use stuff like `GetComponent` to get references to those components. You could try and go for `Component[] components = someGameObject.GetComponents<Component>();` to get all components on a `GameObject` and store them as well .. but as said again it basically will be references to Components .. I don't know what `ES3` does internally and not all component types are supported.

Comment: This definitely feels like you're recreating a prefab (or perhaps, a scene). Is there a good reason you're doing this rather than using prefabs or scenes? Prefabs and scenes will both load more quickly than any custom serialization method.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for [Serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html) and *possibly* [ScriptableObjects](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html).